# What does a portlet bridge do?

Tags: portlet, portal

In an interview today I mentioned that I had done some jsf work in a portlet.  The interviewer asked for specifics on what the portlet-bridge does.  I never looked into it all that much, just used it because I was told it would make jsf work in the portlet.  All I could really say was that it allowed the requests to come from the portal to jsf in a way jsf would understand, and made it play nice.

What exactly does the portlet-bridge do?

Comment: http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the spec linked by Jeremy Walton above.

> 2.1 What is a Portlet Bridge?
>
> The Java™ Portlet Specification
>   defines a set of APIs for directly
>   implementing a portlet.  A portlet
>   bridge is a technology used by a
>   portlet to bridge to an execution
>   environment where differing
>   abstractions are used for rendering
>   markup or processing user
>   interactions. Typically these are
>   well-known, possibly standard web
>   development environments.  Examples
>   include JavaServer™ Faces and Apache
>   Struts.
>
> The portlet bridge acts as the
>   translation engine between the portlet
>   environment and the targeted system. 
>   It expresses the portlet request
>   context to the bridged environment,
>   executes the request and transforms
>   the response as appropriate for the
>   portlet environment.  It provides an
>   abstraction of the portlet environment
>   for the bridged environment, and for
>   developers working within the bridged
>   environment.  These developers are
>   freed to execute Faces views as
>   portlets, without the need to
>   understand the details of the portlet
>   APIs and development model.
>
> To put it simply, a portlet bridge is
>   the technology that allows a Java web
>   developer to execute views developed
>   using other web programming
>   abstractions as portlets without
>   needing to know and or learn about
>   portlet development, concepts, or
>   APIs.
>
> The Portlet Bridge for JavaServer™
>   Faces is the specific bridge
>   technology needed to support this
>   bridging behavior for JavaServer™
>   Faces.